# File is exists when check in Android Activity, but doesn't in Service

Tags: android

My app is to process a video file in background service, before calling the service to process, I will check the file validity in Activity, only proceed when the file is valid, see the code below:

```
    In Activity Class, videoPath is a file path, sample video paths below:
    videoPath= "/storage/emulated/0/Snapchat/Snapchat-23231409.mp4";
    videoPath= "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/AndroVid/video/20171101_163739_1683.mp4"
    videoPath= "/storage/emulated/0/Movies/Messenger/received_1977270162535177.mp4";
    videoPath= "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/VivaVideo/XiaoYing_Video_1509627632219.mp4";

 videoPath="/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/AndroVid/video/20171101_163749_1683.mp4"
    if (videoPath != null) {
        File videoFile = new File(videoPath);
        if (videoFile.exists() && videoFile.length() > 0 && videoFile.canRead()) {
            videoFileValid = true;
        }
    }
    The output videoFileValid return true, so will proceed to Service Class.
```

Then in once the Service starts, I will do this again, and found videoFileValid is false!!!

**Here the videoPath is from activity, so they are exactly the same.**

```
   String videoPath = intent.getExtras().getString(
            VideoConstants.INTENT_VIDEO_PATH);
   if (videoPath != null) {
        File videoFile = new File(videoPath);

        if (videoFile.exists() && videoFile.length() > 0 && videoFile.canRead()) {
            videoFileValid = true;
        }
    }
    Now the videoFileValid return False value !!!
```

Any idea?

Comment: Give more code sample if you want fast answer from somebody .

Comment: @NikolaLukic Thank you :) I've added more code.

Comment: What is the actual value of `videoPath` ? In both cases.

Comment: @greenapps hi I put some sample videoPath thanks.